# Want to display imagename in textview

Tags: android, textview

Developing an app of wallpapers. In xml I have TextView, an ImageView,2 buttons to change images. Images are changing perfectly with buttons. I want to display image name in textview simultaneously as images change with next and back buttons. I used many codes but remained unsuccessful. Plz help to sort out the issue. Here is xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#66DDDD"
    android:weightSum="100" > 
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight"7.62"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#66FFFFFF"
    android:maxHeight="91dip"
    android:maxWidth="47dip"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/r0" /> 
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bprev" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Back" > 
    </Button> 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bnext" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Next" >
    </Button>
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity.

```
 public class Main extends Activity { 
   private ImageView hImageViewPic; 
   private Button iButton, gButton;
   private int currentImage = 0;
   int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 };
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic); 
       iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
       gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev); 
   //Just set one Click listener for the image
      iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener);
      gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener); 
    } 
      View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
          public void onClick(View v) {
   //Increase Counter to move to next Image
          currentImage++; 
          currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
        hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
     }
    };
      View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(View v) {
    //Increase Counter to move to next Image
         currentImage--; 
         currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
       hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
    }
     };
    }
```

So plz guide me what I have to do. Have I need to call the textview or whatever. I am new to android thats why I have completely no idea. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your text view an id, then import it into your Main Activity...

EX: add in xml
android:id="@+id/idTextView"

EX: add in MainActivity
myPicText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTextView);

and in your onClickListener() for buttons
myPicText.setText("whatever you want);

Comment: Thanx for reply but sir I am not understanding this.myPicText.setText (whatever you want);

Comment: when you click the onclicklistner to change picture, you can also change you text. say I wanted it to say dog you would write

Comment: myPicText.setText("dog");

Comment: the other two lines are to set that up

Comment: Thanx. Yes it shows the text  dog. How can the text will change as the image changes.

Comment: I would set up an integer every time the user clicks, and use an if statement to display the text you want for each picture